# sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error: because of apostrophe

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, sqliteopenhelper

The song name  that I want to insert it into my table contains a " ' " (apostrophe )so , there is an error when the request is excuted. How can I fix it

```
Cursor pid = mDB.rawQuery("select Id  FROM MusicPlayer WHERE "Path ='" + sname + "';", null);
```

I am getting sname runtime so .. sname=`/mnt/sdcard/Now Thats What I Call Music 85 [Bubanee]/16 - Let's Get Ready To Rhumble (100% Radio Mix) - PJ & Duncan.mp3`

I get below error..

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT Id FROM MusicPlayer WHERE Path ='/mnt/sdcard/Now Thats What I Call Music 85 [Bubanee]/16 - Let's Get Ready To Rhumble (100% Radio Mix) - PJ & Duncan.mp3';`

Because  sname contain `let's` word with `'` which gives me error.

Comment: Escape the apostrophe

Comment: @RaghavSood how can i escape . i am getting it runtime ..after escaping this again another string may have apostrophe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In theory you could escape `'` as `''` in SQL.

However, it's better to use variable binding. Replace the string literals in SQL with `?` and supply corresponding number of `String`s in an array:

```
Cursor pid = mDB.rawQuery("select Id  FROM MusicPlayer WHERE Path = ?;",
    new String[] { sname });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get details for Sting within comma or someother means use like this cursor.

`Cursor cursor = odb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ITEM + "=?;", new String[]{comboname});`

Thanks laalto sir your answer is work perfectly.