# SQLite.SQLiteException: 'near "s": syntax error' when updating field in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I'm currently working on UWP project and I use sqlite database.In this project I want to update field in sqlite table(classroomteam).When I entered value with apostrophe(') It gives error saying "SQLite.SQLiteException: 'near "s": syntax error'"

This is the code that I used to save updated data to the table

```
public static async Task UpdateTeamName(ClassroomTeamItem classroomTeamItem)
    {
        IWAppUtils.PrintDebug("====Start ", CLASS_NAME, "UpdateTeamName()");
        ClassroomTeam classroomTeam = new ClassroomTeam()
        {

            TeamName = classroomTeamItem.TeamName,
            Id = classroomTeamItem.Id,

        };
        String teamName = classroomTeamItem.TeamName;
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(IWSQLite.DATABASE_NAME);
        //Task<int> a = conn.UpdateAsync(configInfo);
        await conn.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE classroomteam SET TeamName = '"  + classroomTeamItem.TeamName + "' WHERE Id = '" + classroomTeam.Id + "'");
        await conn.CloseAsync();
        IWAppUtils.PrintDebug("====End ", CLASS_NAME, "UpdateTeamName()");
    }
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126209/sqlite-sqliteexception-near-s-syntax-error-because-of-apostrophe) to solve my issue and what I did is applying **new String[] {classroomTeamItem.TeamName }** in the query.Then I didn't get any error but the value is stored as System.String[] not the value I entered in sqlite table.The code I tried as follows.

```
public static async Task UpdateTeamName(ClassroomTeamItem classroomTeamItem)
    {
        IWAppUtils.PrintDebug("====Start ", CLASS_NAME, "UpdateTeamName()");
        ClassroomTeam classroomTeam = new ClassroomTeam()
        {

            TeamName = classroomTeamItem.TeamName,
            Id = classroomTeamItem.Id,

        };
        String teamName = classroomTeamItem.TeamName;
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(IWSQLite.DATABASE_NAME);
        //Task<int> a = conn.UpdateAsync(configInfo);
        await conn.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE classroomteam SET TeamName = '"  + new String[] { classroomTeam.TeamName } + "' WHERE Id = '" + classroomTeam.Id + "'");
        await conn.CloseAsync();
        IWAppUtils.PrintDebug("====End ", CLASS_NAME, "UpdateTeamName()");
    }
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql string about how to update field is:

```
string SQL_UPDATE = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET Value = ? WHERE Key = ?";
```

So you could try to change your update string to

```
await db.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE classroomteam SET TeamName = " + classroomTeamItem.TeamName + " WHERE Id = " + classroomTeam.Id);
```

Or you can query for the specific data is most straightforwardly done using the **Table** method and then update your field. For example:

```
private async void update(ClassroomTeamItem classroomTeamItem)
{
    var query = db.Table<ClassroomTeam>().Where(s => s.Id==classroomTeam.Id);
    var result = await query.ToListAsync();
    foreach (var s in result)
    {
        s.TeamName = classroomTeamItem.TeamName;
        await db.UpdateAsync(s);
    }
}
```